# Third Normal Form

Tags: database-design, normalization, database-normalization

I asked to create a 3NF of a Library System with a min of 5 tables. And with my understanding with normalization, I made this. I just want to confirm if my works is already normalized in 3NF? Or what will I gonna do to make it in 3NF?

[image]

Comment: The only thing I would recommend is cleaning up your column names. Use BookID across all tables.

Comment: OK. And is this already in 3NF?

Comment: Without a list of Functional Dependencies one cannot really evaluate whether a schema is in any particular normal form or not. Even without the FD's, I have a few suspicions that there may be problems with the BorrowedBooks table.

Comment: This is a learning exercise I would assume, rather than a real business problem? Firstly, get yourself a decent modelling tool that can draw proper ER diagrams. Your diagram is practically useless for the purpose because it doesn't show relevant info (lacks candidate keys, foreign keys and cardinality). No one can say for sure about 3NF without seeing the set of dependencies the schema is supposed to satisfy. My guess is there are things here that probably violate 3NF. But that's just a guess based on column names.

Comment: Best guess based on column names and my interpretation of keys -- yes. Does not make it a good design though. That `{OtherAuthor}` invites `NULLs` and what if a book has more than two? Auto-increment keys are not silver bullet, you need candidate keys for logical design and consideration of normal forms; then later you can add a surrogate key (ID) when deriving physical model -- for example `{Book, Borrower, BorrowedDate}`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you're not taking into account a borrower borrowing a book more than once. Also, you need to have a reference table for a 1:n relationship between books and authors (a book can have more than 2 authors, so remove the author columns in `BookTitles`). Once you create this reference, you should be at 3NF.

Depending on the complexity, should the student's information be stored in a student table, then referenced as "borrower" ?

Comment: `should the student's information be stored in a student table, then referenced as "borrower?` Yes, and the course should probably be N:M related to student (and not to borrower)

Comment: 'As far as I can tell, you're not taking into account a borrower borrowing a book more than once' In the table BorrowedBooks, borrower is not a unique key.